# If post has custom field then display css-class

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, posts

I would like to display a different icon in an `i` tag if a post has a certain key of a customized field. In my example `Preis`:

```
<i class="(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Preis', true) != '' ? echo "fa fa-check" : echo "fa fa-times")">
```

However, as output I get nothing back.

Any suggestions, what is wrong with my `IF-ELSE` structure?

Comment: You're missing PHP tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably ran into problems with escaping code and HTML from each other.

Try this (added line breaks just for better readability):

```
<i class="
    <?php 
         echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Preis', true) != '') ? 
          'fa fa-check' : 'fa fa-times';
    ?>
">
```